# Weighted Average or Non-Weighted Average for this?

Tags: statistics

I surveyed people for a thesis I made, and want to calculate the standard deviation of their results, however I am not sure whether or not I should use weighted average or non-weighted average, my question was

> On a scale of 1-10, how confident are you in yourself, 1 being none at all, and 10 being the most confidence?

Now, should I set my average up like this:

$$ avg = n(1) + n(2) + n(3) + n(4) + n(5) ... n(10) / 10$$ where *n* equals the amount of people who chose 1,2,3 etc or do I calculate it with a normal average such as : $$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 ... + 10/10$$ where I do not use the frequency?

Comment: what do you mean by the second sum?

Comment: @qbert The first sum uses the frequency (which is n) so lets say 4 people chose 3 as an option it would be n(1) + n(2) + 4(3) + ... n(10) / 10, the second is just a regular average calculation with no frequency at all, so since the options are 1 - 10 it would be the same as above with no frequency used.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your surveys come back,

5,5,6,7,7,7,8,8,9,9

You could say: (5+5+6+7+7+7+8+8+9+9)/10,

or you could say:(2/10)*5+(1/10)6+(3/10)7+(2/10)*8+(1/10)*9

And either way you will get the same result.